# Log4Net to-Email in user.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, log4net

in a big project we use log4net.
At the moment we have a normal global web.config:

```
 <appender name="RestartSmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
        <to value="koch@xxxx.de" />
        <from value="info@xxxxx.de" />
        <subject value="ccccc />
        <smtpHost value="xxxx" />
        <bufferSize value="512" />
        <lossy value="true" />
</appender>
```

No we want to have the to-setting in a user.config so every developer gets his own emails and not 1 developer or 1 email account get all emails.

How is that possible?

Comment: So do you want this to work in just the development environment, or when deployed to a server?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to make this work locally is set the email address using log4net's `GlobalContext`: this must be done before log4net is configured.

```
string email = "dev1@example.com"; // Get value from user.config or default
GlobalContext.Properties["emailto"] = email;
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(…);
```

Then in the log4net configuration you have to mark the `'To'` attribute as a `PatternString` and retrieve the value:

```
<to type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{emailto}" />
<from value="info@xxxxx.de" />
...
```